# JS: replace is not replacing information

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming an action where after a button press, games on the platform "console" or "pc" is shown. I would like it when the button for "pc" is pressed first, all pc games are shown. And after when the "console" button is pressed, all "pc" games are removed and then all "console" games are appended

code for the buttons is this:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="searchPC()">PC</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="searchCon()">Console</button>
```

code for the function is similar across the two buttons;

```
function searchPC() {
  $("search").replaceWith(`<div></div>`);

  axios
    .get(`${baseUrl}/game/PC`)
    .then((response) => {
      const posts = response.data;
      console.log(posts);
      posts.forEach((post) => {
        const postPHtml = `
          <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
              <div class="card-body ">
                  <p class="card-text">${post.title}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                  <p>${post.description}</p>
                  <p>SGD$${post.price}</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/gamesinfo/${post.gameid}">Home</a>
              </div>
          </div>
          `;

        $("#search").replaceWith(postPHtml);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

What I have attempted is to replace any info with an empty div, then adding the desired information, however, it still shows the older information (referring to above, "pc" is still shown even after pressing "console".

Furthermore, I have more than 1 card to add, ie there are >2 sets of information for console and pc games

original file with js included is:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Friendbook</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class='bg-dark'>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <div class="">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://localhost:8082/images/image.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:40px;" id="logo">
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="searchPC()">PC</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="searchCon()">Console</button>
            </nav>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark mt-1">
                <form class="form-inline ml-2" action="/action_page.php">
                    <input class="form-control" id='searchP' type="text" placeholder="Search by Price">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
                <form class="form-inline ml-2" action="/action_page.php">
                    <input class="form-control" id='searchN' type="text" placeholder="Search by Name">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </nav>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
            <div class="card-body col-md-10">
                <h4 class='title '>Search Games</h4>
                <div id="search" class="container-fluid md-6 sm-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
            <div class="card-body col-md-10">
                <h4 class='title '>All Games</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2rem;">

            <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-12 ml-5">
                <div id="posts" class="container-fluid md-6 sm-6">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class='bg-dark p-3'>
        <div class='ml-2 mt-2'>
            <form>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="logout()">logout</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8081";
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const loggedInUserID = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("loggedInUserID"));

        if (token === null /* || isNaN(loggedInUserID) */) {
            window.location.href = "/login/";
        } else {
            axios.get(`${baseUrl}/gameall/all`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const posts = response.data;
                    console.log(posts)
                    posts.forEach((post) => {
                        const postHtml = `
                    <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <p class="card-text">${post.title}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <p>${post.description}</p>
                            <p>SGD$${post.price}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/gamesinfo/${post.gameid}">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;

                        $("#posts").append(postHtml);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            /*
            axios.get(`${baseUrl}/game/console/`)
            .then((response) => {
                const posts = response.data;
                console.log(posts)
                posts.forEach((post) => {
                    const postHtml = `
                <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                    <div class="card-body ">
                        <p class="card-text">${post.title}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        ${post.description}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/gamesinfo/${post.gameid}">Home</a>
                        <p class="card-text">${post.price}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `;

                    $("#posts").append(postHtml);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });*/

            //acts as addpost api
            $("#create-post-form").submit((event) => {
                // prevents the page from refreshing
                event.preventDefault();

                const requestBody = {
                    text_body: $("#create-post-form-body").val(),
                    fk_poster_id: loggedInUserID
                };

                // create the post
                axios.post(`${baseUrl}/posts/`, requestBody)
                    .then((response) => {
                        // reset form value.
                        $("#create-post-form-body").val("");

                        // fetch the post with the returned postID
                        axios.get(`${baseUrl}/posts/${response.data.postID}`)
                            .then((response) => {
                                const post = response.data;
                                const postHtml = `
                    <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                        <div class="card-body sm-6">
                            <p class="card-text">${post.text_body}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            ${post.created_at}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
                                $("#posts").append(postHtml);
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error);
                            });
                    });
            });
        }
        function logout() {
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            localStorage.removeItem('role')
            localStorage.removeItem('id')
        }
        function searchPC() {

            axios.get(`${baseUrl}/game/PC`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const posts = response.data;
                    console.log(posts)
                    posts.forEach((post) => {
                        const postPHtml = `
                    <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <p class="card-text">${post.title}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <p>${post.description}</p>
                            <p>SGD$${post.price}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/gamesinfo/${post.gameid}">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
                        $("#search").appendChild(postPHtml);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
        function searchCon() {
            axios.get(`${baseUrl}/game/console`)
                .then((response) => {
                    const posts = response.data;
                    posts.forEach((post) => {
                        const postCHtml = `
                    <div class="card sm-6" style="margin-top: 2rem;">
                        <div class="card-body ">
                            <p class="card-text">${post.title}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <p>${post.description}</p>
                            <p>SGD$${post.price}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/gamesinfo/${post.gameid}">Home</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;

                        $("#search").appendChild(postCHtml);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: The selector at the top of your function (`$("search")`) doesn't have a prefix like `#` or `.`

Comment: What does your original html look like?

Comment: `replaceWith` will replace the element entirely, once you replace `#search`, the next time you query the DOM for it, it will have been removed. You may want to either ensure your new elements have the same identifiers, or replace the content of `#search` rather than the entire container element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **html(htmlString) **

**Description**: Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements

replace `$("#search").replaceWith(postPHtml);`

with `$("#search").html(postPHtml);`

see:https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: it successfully replaced the old information, however, it still is not showing the 'full information'

I have 2 games with the platform of pc, after implementing this, I am only shown 1out of the 2

How do you suggest I fix it?

Furthermore, it is only showing the last information. Ie, the second stack of information is shown instead of the first and second